# Is there a concise way to substitute return value of a function?

Tags: dash-shell

I'm putting together some unit tests for a `dash` shell script I've inherited and, given the *large* number of tests we want to add, I want to keep them as concise as possible.

To do this, I've added a `check` helper function to handle pass or failure of a test. It basically receives the return code `$?` from the previous command and passes or fails the test based on that. This allows me to simply implement a one-liner test (of which there are *many*) as:

```
for td in 1.1.1.999 {{lots of other invalid IPs}} ; do
    isInvalidIpV4 ${td} ; check is-true $? "Checking ${td} is invalid"
done
for seg in 0 1 9 10 99 100 254 255 ; do
    td="${seg}.${seg}.${seg}.${seg}"
    isInvalidIpV4 ${td} ; check is-false $? "Checking ${td} is valid"
done
```

Now this is reasonably good since it gets each test down to a single line but, in my OCD quest for perfection, I wonder if there's even *more* scope for reduction.

I know that, like `bash`, there is the capability to run a command and use its *output* in another command, along the lines of:

```
echo "Lowercase name is $(echo PaxDiablo | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')"
```

but I was wondering if there were a way to do this same substitution with the *return code* of a command.

That would mean my test line would be able to have that annoyingly repeated `$?` removed, changing from:

```
isInvalidIpV4 ${td} ; check pass $? "${td} should be invalid"
```

to something like:

```
check pass $[isInvalidIpV4 ${td}] "${td} should be invalid"
```

where `$[]` is the mythical "use return code" substitution operator.

Does `dash` have this facility or is there a more concise way to do it than what I've currently done?

Just keep in mind, other shells are not an option here, this is an embedded system for which `dash` is the only shell provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ! isInvalidIpV4 $td
then
  echo $td should be invalid
fi
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.